# Flex Regex find match between 2 characters in url

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am looking for a regex to parse the part between a = and an & to get the first url variable.

Example url:

```
http://vandooren.be?v=123456&test=123
```

I need to get the 123456 from the string.

My last try was

```
var pattern:RegExp = /\=|\&/;
var result:Array = pattern.exec(dg.selectedItem.link[0]);
trace(result.index, " - ", result);
```

But i am still getting errors.

Comment: Is there a URI/URL(Parser) class? Otherwise, you can split at `?` take the last token, then split along `&`, then for each token, find the one starting with the name and split along `=`.

Comment: yes i will get the variable from the url so stupid i didn't think about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this follow code.

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /(?<==).+(?=&)/;   
var str:String = "http://vandooren.be?v=123456&test=123";
var result:Array = myPattern.exec(str);
trace(result[0]); //123456
```

---

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /(?<==).+(?=&)/;   
var str:String = "youtube.com/watch?v=nCgQDjiotG0&feature=youtube_gdata";
var result:Array = myPattern.exec(str);
trace(result[0]); //nCgQDjiotG0
```

---

**`Assertions`**

```
foo(?=bar)  Lookahead assertion. The pattern foo will only match if followed by a match of pattern bar.
foo(?!bar)  Negative lookahead assertion. The pattern foo will only match if not followed by a match of pattern bar.
(?<=foo)bar Lookbehind assertion. The pattern bar will only match if preceeded by a match of pattern foo.
(?<!foo)bar Negative lookbehind assertion. The pattern bar will only match if not preceeded by a match of pattern foo.
```

Comment: it works on that url but when i get an url like this 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCgQDjiotG0&feature=youtube_gdata' it returns null

Comment: my answer edited. it works well a following url 'youtube.com/watch?v=nCgQDjiotG0&feature=youtube_gdata' recheck please.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. I just copied what u gave in then i retyped it myself and it worked :) ty

Comment: I don't understand. no Problem. carefully rechek please sir.

Comment: Too complicated, too much backtracking. I'd go with the more straightforward /?[^=]+=([^&]+)/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<==)[^&]*(?=&)
```

This regex will match whatever is after the '=' and before the first next '&'.

Comment: this gives an error in flex :| i tried something similar before turns out it needs to meet certain conditions